# TypeError: Entry.get() got an unexpected keyword argument 'textvariable'

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, tkinter-entry

I was trying to run the following code using **Tkinter** libary -

```
long = tk.Label(menu_add, text='Longitude', font=letter_font)
long_input = Entry.get(menu_add, textvariable=long, font=letter_font)
```

I got this error -

```
File "C:\Users\User\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\seismology.py", line 48, in add
 long_input = Entry.get(menu_add, textvariable=long, font=letter_font)
TypeError: Entry.get() got an unexpected keyword argument 'textvariable'
```

Using **tk.Entry** instead of **Entry.get** fixes the problem, but my objective is to **save the user entry** to a file later. Below code uses Tk.Entry -

```
long = tk.Entry(menu_add, text='Longitude', font=letter_font)
long_input = tk.Entry(menu_add, textvariable=long, font=letter_font)
```

Then I got this error -

```
File "C:\Users\User\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\seismology.py", line 26, in save
    open('seismology.csv', 'a').write('\n'.join(lst_data) + '\n')
TypeError: sequence item 0: expected str instance, Entry found
```

Code to save in the file -

```
def save():
    open('seismology.csv', 'a').write('\n'.join(lst_data) + '\n')
```

The **values** of the **Entries** are saved to an **list**, named **lst_data** to later be saved to the **file** -

```
long.grid(row=3, column=0)
long_input.grid(row=3, column=1)

d = long_input

global lst_data
lst_data = [a,b,c,d,e,f]
```

full code-

> https://i.stack.imgur.com/PZKsi.jpg

Any help is appreciated! ^^

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. The error mentions a variable `lst_data` but you haven't provided any code that defines that variable. Also, I strongly recommend you save the data you want to write in a variable before calling `write`. That way you can more easily examine the value immediately before writing it.

Comment: hello @BryanOakley as requested, heres the code which has the `lst_data`.
`lst_data` is supossed to be an list where all the Entries are saved in order to later be saved on the file.

`long.grid(row=3, column=0)`
`long_input.grid(row=3, column=1)`

`d = long_input`

`global lst_data`
`lst_data = [a,b,c,d,e,f]`

the code shared here only has the part where it does the error

Comment: Please don't put code in the comments. You can [edit]  your question to add requested information.

Comment: The error obviously tells you that you cannot use `Entry` in `.join()` because `d` is an `Entry` widget.  So change `d = long_input` to `d = long_input.get()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use the `Entry.get()` method in Python as Entry is a Tkinter module, so you have to insert it as `tk.Entry()` only.

As for the second error, you are getting this error because you are trying to use a list type in a `.join()` code. `.join()` only accepts a string so try replacing `open('seismology.csv', 'a').write('\n'.join(lst_data) + '\n')` with `open('seismology.csv', 'a').write('\n'.join(str(lst_data)) + '\n')`

Then your error will be fixed.